# TypeError: exchange[a].fetchTicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ccxt

I am using ccxt library and I have a problem to get tickers from different exchanges from an array..

I have this array:

```
let exchanges= ['binance', 'bittrex']; 
let symbol = 'BTT/BTC' ;
```

And If I try to get tickers from these exchanges it shows me this error:

> TypeError: exchange[a].fetchTicker is not a function

```
for(let a in exchanges){
    let exchangePrice = await exchanges[a].fetchTicker ( symbol )
}
```

If I type `binance.fetchTicker ( symbol )` it works fine, but Idk how to fetch all exchanges from my list..!

Comment: Your array `let exchanges= ['binance', 'bittrex']; ` is an array of string. Did you try `let exchanges= [binance, bittrex];` to remove the quotes like this?

Comment: That worked for exchanges, but in fact I have a list of symbols too. And I can't put symbols in array without quotes, because they have the slash in the middle like "ETH/BTC"

How can I fetch multiple symbols, in one exchange.!

Comment: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/js/looping-over-specific-symbols-of-all-exchanges.js